# chef-client permission denied on root user

Tags: linux, chef-infra

running the chef client like so:

```
root@chef-production-server:~# chef-client -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json
```

output :

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.8.1
[2016-04-10T14:11:12+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.8.1 ***
[2016-04-10T14:11:12+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 8556
[2016-04-10T14:11:13+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[sensu_client::default@0.1.0]", "recipe[simple_server::application_server_recipe@0.1.2]", "recipe[mongodb::default@0.16.2]"] from CLI options
[2016-04-10T14:11:13+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[sensu_client::default@0.1.0], recipe[simple_server::application_server_recipe@0.1.2], recipe[mongodb::default@0.16.2]]
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/libsnoopy.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
bla bla bla

cannot create directory ‘/home/jenkins/.rvm’: Permission denied
```

it has worked before, not anymore. also tried

```
 sudo chef-client -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an ld preload set to force-open "libsnoopy" in all processes. From github the appears to be some kind of simplistic audit tool. For whatever reason, that file isn't loading so that would be something to check on. Try removing it from the preload config. Also check that `/home` exists and is mounted correctly.